# How can I get the quantity both expired and not yet expired?

Tags: mysql

I subtract the quantity of expired medicine to the actual stock. I use this `(IFNULL(tbl_medicine.quantity - SUM(tbl_received.received_quantity),0)) AS Total` and `DATE(NOW()) > tbl_received.expiration_date` to get the date of expired medicine. My problem is I can't get the quantity that is not expired yet. How can I get the quantity of not yet expired with expired medicine? Can somebody help me with my problem? Here's my query...

```
SELECT tbl_med.sup_med_id, tbl_med.quantity, 
 tbl_received.received_quantity, tbl_med.status, 
 (IFNULL(tbl_med.quantity - SUM(tbl_received.received_quantity),0)) AS Total 
FROM 
 tbl_med 
INNER JOIN 
 tbl_received ON tbl_received.sup_med_id = tbl_med.sup_med_id 
WHERE 
 tbl_med.status = 'Active' AND DATE(NOW()) > tbl_received.expiration_date AND 
 tbl_med.barangay_id = 19
GROUP BY 
 sup_med_id HAVING Total > 0 
ORDER BY 
 sup_med_id
```

output of query above

```
sup_med_id  quantity  received_quantity  status   Total
3           1800      1000               Active   800
7           1800      1000               Active   800
```

tbl_med & tbl_received table

```
id   sup_med_id  received_quantity  expiration_date
1    3           1000               2019-09-04
2    7           1000               2019-09-04
3    9           1800               2022-09-04

medicine_id  sup_med_id  quantity  status    barangay_id
1            3           1800      Active    19
2            7           1800      Active    19
3            9           1800      Active    19
```

I want this to happen...

```
sup_med_id  quantity  received_quantity  status   Total
3           1800      1000               Active   800
7           1800      1000               Active   800
9           1800      1800               Active   1800
```

I just want to display the quantity to Total if the medicine is not expired yet

Comment: If you want to get the expired and the not expired, simply remove the condition filtering only the expired ones

Comment: Get rid of `AND DATE(NOW()) > tbl_received.expiration_date`

Comment: @Barmar  The problem is also minus even the medicine is not expired yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact you're only joining when the expiration date is in the past. To solve it that check should be removed from the `WHERE` clause and done in the `SUM` of expired quantities instead:

```
SELECT tbl_med.sup_med_id, tbl_med.quantity, 
  tbl_received.received_quantity, tbl_med.status, 
  (tbl_med.quantity 
   - SUM(CASE WHEN NOW() > tbl_received.expiration_date 
              THEN tbl_received.received_quantity 
              ELSE 0 
         END)
  ) AS Total 
FROM 
  tbl_med 
INNER JOIN 
  tbl_received ON tbl_received.sup_med_id = tbl_med.sup_med_id 
WHERE 
  tbl_med.status = 'Active' AND 
  tbl_med.barangay_id = 19
GROUP BY 
  sup_med_id HAVING Total > 0 
ORDER BY 
  sup_med_id
```

I haven't tested the query myself, but I believe it should achieve what you want

Comment: Glad I could help!